# Is there an analytic form for the Hellinger distance between von Mises distributions?

Tags: distributions, distance-functions, von-mises-distribution

Is there an analytic form for the Hellinger distance between von Mises distributions?

Comment: What is your definition of "analytic form"? (What people "accept" as closed-form solutions varies, which is why I ask.) With things like modified Bessel functions (which I wouldn't consider a "closed-form expression") stuck in the denominator, it seems like there may be little hope.